# Implement Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on Resteasy + Netty server

Tags: java, netty, resteasy

Integrating Resteasy in my netty 4 + Guice application works perfectly using server adapter provided by Resteasy (great job guys).

Now my JAX-RS server runs on a different port as my HTTP server (also based on Netty).

So, I need to implement Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on my Resteasy server by adding following HTTP headers to the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length
```

For now, I have forked NettyJaxrsServer and RestEasyHttpResponseEncoder classes and it works quite good (but not a very "clean" solution to me).

I just wonder how to add those headers to response using something like a customized encoder that I could add to my Netty pipeline (or something else...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution : create a SimpleChannelInboundHandler like this:

```
public class CorsHeadersChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<NettyHttpRequest> {
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, NettyHttpRequest request) throws Exception {
        request.getResponse().getOutputHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request.getResponse().getOutputHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        request.getResponse().getOutputHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length");

        ctx.fireChannelRead(request);
    }
}
```

and add this to Netty pipeline just before RestEasyHttpResponseEncoder.

NOTE: Finnally I have added RestEasyHttpRequestDecoder, RestEasyHttpResponseEncoder and RequestHandler at the end of my existing Netty Http server pipeline, so I don't need CORS headers anymore.